# Please tell me the type of System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker.Format custom

Tags: vb.net

I'm wondering if one of the custom DateTimePicke format is yyyy, MM, dd, hh: mm and is already built in or can be used.

Comment: There are no custom `DateTimePicker` formats. Formatting `DateTime` values is the same no matter the context. Start reading about formatting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types). The format specifiers provided in the subtopics apply to all formatting scenarios, including controls, binding, the `ToString` and `String.Format` methods and string interpolation. In your case, you set `Format` to `Custom` and then assign the appropriate format specifier to `CustomFormat`. It's custom. You choose whatever you want.

Comment: The built-in formats are Long, Short and Time.  What they actually look like depends on the user's locale, the format is one they'll easily recognize since it matches the way they see dates anywhere else.  You need Custom if you prefer your own format.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio designer, select the DateTimePicker and in properties set Format to Custom and then set the Custom Format property to whatever you want it to be, in this case yyyy, MM, dd, hh: mm  (or HH if you want 24 hour time).